# Unable to display array values on drop down menu

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I am trying to code a drop down menu where I try to get an array to be displayed on a `UITableView` when a button is pressed. However, the entire mechanism works without having the values displayed. I am able to see the cell borders and scroll but no values can be seen :( Appreciate any help!

(My code)

```
import UIKit
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dropDownButton: UIButton!

    var fruityList = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear", "Banana", "Peach"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func dropDownButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if tableView.isHidden {
            animate(toggle: true)
        } else {
            animate(toggle: false)
        }
    }

    func  animate(toggle:Bool) {
        if toggle {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.tableView.isHidden = false
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

                self.tableView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruityList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruityList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set `dataSource` and `delegate` of tableView?

Comment: Try like this, cell.textLabel?.text = "Label". To check, ur code is right or wrong.

Comment: Check Delegate andDatasource, as Chanchal said.